# URL rewrite issue with CakePHP

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using CakePHP framework 2.2.2

I want to create personalize URL for user if user enter username=pragnesh
then they can access my site like `http://pragnesh.example.com` same as in `blinksale.com`

---

My URL `http://example.com/test/users/front_home`

I want to access it as `http://test.example.com/users/front_home`

My URL: `http://example.com/test/setting/pages`
can be access as: `http://test.example.com/setting/pages`

any URL: `http://example.com/test/xxxxx/xxxxx`
can be access as: `http://test.example.com/xxxxx/xxxxx`

---

**OR**

---

URL `http://example.com/users/front_home?site=test`

I want to access it as `http://test.example.com/users/front_home`

My URL: `http://example.com/setting/pages?site=test`
can be access as: `http://test.example.com/setting/pages`

any URL: `http://example.com/xxxxx/xxxxx?site=test`
can be access as: `http://test.example.com/xxxxx/xxxxx`

---

My question may be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328636/my-cakephp-2-2-site-not-working-on-subdomain
but there is no answer posted

I have tried below code in `\app\webroot\.htaccess`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649890/htaccess-subdomai-part-2

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([^&]*&)*site=[^&]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example.com
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*).php$ /$1.php?user=%1 [QSA,L,R]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938781/url-rewrite-for-subdomain

```
# capture first part of host name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
# make sure site= query parameter isn't there
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)site= [NC]
# rewrite to current URI?site=backererence #1 from host name
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?site=%1 [L,QSA]
```

but both not working for me.

my root .htaccss file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`\app\.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

`\app\webroot\.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Virtual Host in `httpd.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
   DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/bsale"
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/bsale">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**HOST FILE**

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
127.0.0.1   *.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do would be easier at the application level instead of the .hhtaccess level. What you could do is create a single application hosted on the server and each user has a dns record pointed to that application...

eg:
application is hosted on server 1.1.1.1

DNS config is...

```
app-server    IN    A    1.1.1.1
user1         IN   CNAME app-server.domain.com
user2         IN   CNAME app-server.domain.com
user2         IN   CNAME app-server.domain.com
```

What this would do is point all the DNS records to your application and then in your application you simply detect the domain name using whatever native function in your chosen language returns the domain name and then your application handles it as required. This is how most systems are setup that you are talking about andd it minimises configuration requirements as you only need to add a new DNS record each time a new user is created instead of needing to add a new DNS record as well as a new vhost configuration only to host a htaccess file. In addition URL rewrites in apache don't work cross domain and will instead act as a redirect instead of a rewrite.